# Fluent NHibernate OptimisticLock.None() causes "The string 'none' is not a valid Boolean value."

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, xml-validation, optimistic-locking

I'm using the following mapping:

```
public class LoadMap : IAutoMappingOverride<Load> {
    public void Override(AutoMapping<Load> mapping) {
        mapping.HasMany(x => x.Bids).OptimisticLock.None();
        mapping.Version(x => x.Version);
    }
}
```

But when I try to create the session I get the following exception:

> [FormatException: The string 'none' is not a valid Boolean value.]
>
> [XmlSchemaValidationException: The 'optimistic-lock' attribute is invalid - The value 'none' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:boolean' - The string 'none' is not a valid Boolean value.]

I'm using NHibernate 2.1.2.4000 and I was using Fluent NHibernate 1.0RTM, but tried the latest build 636 just to be sure this isn't something that was fixed recently or something.

As a side note, **in case I'm doing this all wrong**, I would like to be able to make changes to the .Bids list without incrementing Version. I saw an example on [Ayende's blog](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/07/nhibernate-mapping-ltpropertygt.aspx) that did what I wanted with properties.

Comment: I'm starting to think that the <bag /> map should have an Optimistic Lock = true|false. I'm having a hard time finding examples online to confirm this. In which case, why does Fluent NHibernate's HasMany use .OptimisticLock.None() instead of .Not.OptimisticLock()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's a bug. [Valid values for the optimistic-lock property are true|false](http://knol.google.com/k/fabio-maulo/nhibernate-chapter-6/1nr4enxv3dpeq/9#6%282E%294%282E%29%28C2%29%28A0%29One%282D%29To%282D%29Many_Associations), as you state in your comment. It appears that Fluent NHibernate is setting the property to none but I would generate the XML schema to be sure.

Comment: Yep, the value in the XML is 'none' instead of 'false'.

Answer (score 1):

As Jamie says, looks like a bug (or missing feature) in Fluent NHibernate. I've added a hack to allow setting False and True on OptimisticLock in [my github fork](https://github.com/sinelaw/fluent-nhibernate/tree/noaml). It seems to work.